# Custom calendar layout - collision detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am trying to generate a calendar (1 day a page at the moment) on a web page using javascript (with jquery).

I want the calendar events to be displayed logically and not to overlap.  The widths should adjust based on the number of events etc.  Here's a diagram of requirements i borrowed from a different post:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaMNO.png]

I started out working from the answer (Dan M) on this post ->[custom calendar with event divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562711/custom-calendar-with-event-divs). And it got me quite far.  But the approved answer has some flaws and is easy to break. So starting again but using the same approach as the best answer I have managed to put together this jsbin -> http://jsbin.com/agocuz/3/.  If you have a look at the code you can see that the problem is with my 14:20 event.  It only collides with 2 other events so takes up 33% of the width.  However, the event it clashes with clashes with 3 other events.  (scratches head).

I cant really see a good solution to this.  So far I'm using the opacity via hsla to show any dodgy overlap.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not necessarily looking for someone to code the solution for me, just to give me a heads up on the pseudo code approach would be great.

if you look at the similar question that I linked to and want to see the answer breaking then use the following data :

```
var events = [
  {id: 1, start: 0, end: (3 * 60)},
  {id: 2, start: 0, end: (6.5 * 60)},
  {id: 3, start: 60, end: (15-9) * 60},
  {id: 4, start: 80, end: (13-9) * 60},
  {id: 5, start: (12-9)*60, end: (14-9)*60}, 
 ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only check how many events exist in a specific time.

You need to also check what their size is and use the minimum size appropriate (*in case they are smaller due to previous overlap - as is your case*)

So instead of checking against the `ts.length` you need to check for the size of the events at that timeslot..

```
var max = ts.length;
ts.forEach(function(id){
    var evt = EventsById[id];
    max=(evt.numcolumns>max)?evt.numcolumns:max;
  });

if (event.numcolumns <= max) {    
    event.numcolumns = max;
  }
```

Demo at http://jsbin.com/iFUNetE/1/

---

**Update**

Added this code

```
 // UPDATE CODE AFTER COMMENT
  // fix numcolumns
  for (m=0; m<MINUTESINDAY; m++) {
    ts = timeslots[m];
    for (e=0; e<ts.length; e++) {
      event = EventsById[ ts[e] ];
      var max = ts.length;
      ts.forEach(function(id){
          var evt = EventsById[id];
          max=(evt.numcolumns>max)?evt.numcolumns:max;
        });

      if (event.numcolumns <= max) {    
        event.numcolumns = max;
      }
    }
  }
```

to solve the issue identified by @guioconnor in the comments.

Demo at http://jsbin.com/fopuxakabunu/1/

Comment: This solution doesn't solve the problem either. If you have a sequence of events that collectively collide but there is not full pairwise collision the algorithm breaks. (see jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/qinew/1). You'll have to go back recursively to the events that collided in the past with the current event and update those too.

Comment: My solution is not easy to put on pastebin because I'm creating several objects and they interact in non-trivial ways (I'll try to create a reduced version if I get some time) but essentially the solution is to keep, for each event, a list of the previous (not future, that would be redundant, though not incorrect) collisions, and recurrently update those when an event changes it's numcolumns. This way, you revisit events even after based on collisions of collisions and not only direct collisions.

Comment: @guioconnor posted an updated code that solves this. The concept is that since we already store the number of columns per event, just iterating over the timeslots a second time and updating the column numbers (based on the max) will fix the problem.

Comment: That's an interesting approach.